# Log Text File writing Continuously

Tags: vb.net

I have written a small program; write log text in to file, but Log Text File is writing continuously. I want to write only once if the condition is true or false please help me to find a solution.

```
Private Sub Comp1_Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Comp1_Timer.Tick
    ReDim VariableHandle(1)
    Dim AirComp1On As Boolean
    ' Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(filepath)


    VariableHandle(1) = TcClient.CreateVariableHandle("GVL1.bComp1Start")
    AirComp1On = TcClient.ReadAny(VariableHandle(1), GetType(Boolean))

    If AirComp1On = True Then
        PictureBox15.Image = My.Resources.Resources.Compres_on

        Using writer As New StreamWriter(filepath, True)
            writer.WriteLine("SkyHab:Compressor Started " & DateAndTime.Now())
            writer.Close()
        End Using
    Else

        PictureBox15.Image = My.Resources.Resources.compressor
        Using writer As New StreamWriter(filepath, True)
            writer.WriteLine("SkyHab:Compressor Stopped" & DateAndTime.Now())
            writer.Close()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Any chance you can clarify your question a bit better?

Comment: Hi, If the compressor On , then event log ' Compressor  Started' should be written in a text file at once, but here it is writing continuously, that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

Keep a static (or global) variable initialized to zero, and set it to 1 if the compressor started or 0 if the compresser stopped.

```
Static status As Integer = 0
```

In the tick handler, output to the log only if the status variable is zero or if the status has changed.